# cannot use activesheet.select after application.visible=false

Tags: excel, vba

I have to hide my excel workbook and just show userform.

I executed `application.visible=false` and `userform1.show`. It does the work.

In my code, i have used `activeworkbook.sheets(1).select`. But it gives me an error. it says:

> `select method of worksheet class failed`

How to access various sheets in this workbook? I have used `thisworkbook` also. It says the same error.

Answer (score 0):

once your application isn't visible you can't select any object of it

this is another reason why Select/Selection/Activate/ActiveXXX is always a bad thing

rather use fully qualified range references

```
With ActiveWorkbook
    With .Worksheets(1) '<--| reference first Worksheet
        .Range("A1").Value = 1 '<-- set its "A1" cell value
        '...
    End With

    With .Worksheets(2) '<--| reference second Worksheet
        .Range("A1").Value = 1 '<-- set its "A1" cell value
        '...
    End With
End With
```